# How to find time index when equal to time stamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a pandas data frame like this with a time index:

```
 2018-01-19 01:32:00.000
 2018-01-19 01:32:00.500
 2018-01-19 01:32:01.000    
 2018-01-19 01:32:01.500
 2018-01-19 01:32:02.000
 2018-01-19 01:32:02.500    
 2018-01-19 01:32:03.000
 2018-01-19 01:32:03.500
```

And an array of time stamps like this:

```
 np.array(['2018-01-19 01:32:00.000', '2018-01-19 01:32:01.500', '2018-01-19 01:32:03:00'])
```

How do I return the index values that match my array of time stamps? Such that I return an array that looks like this:

```
 np.array(0, 3, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check with `get_indexer`

```
df.index.get_indexer(a)
array([ 0,  3,  6])
```

Comment: what is a? the np.array? i am not gettign the answer

Comment: I am not the OP but it is not working for me. May be it does work for OP.